# Jinja2 custom function giving positional argument error

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I have a custom filter in Jinja that requires two arguments, I am calling the function inside my Jinja template and I am getting an TypeError about positional arguments. That my function takes two (correct) but that 3 were given (incorrect)

Here is the function code

```
# Get the total balance of a student to display for an instructor
def get_stud_balance(inst_id, stud_id):
    balance = 0
    stud_balance = Packages.query.filter(Packages.inst_id == inst_id, Packages.stud_id == stud_id).all()
    for row in stud_balance:
        balance += row.balance
    return balance
```

This is how it is registered..

```
app.jinja_env.filters['get_balance'] = filters.get_stud_balance
```

This is how I am trying to call it..

```
{% for row in studs %} <!-- START for loop -->
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-heading"><center>{{ row.first_name }} {{ row.last_name }}</center></div>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <li>Cell Phone: {{ row.cell|phone }}</li>
                            <li>Home Phone: {{ row.home|phone }}</li>
                            <li>Email: {{ row.email }} </li>
                            <li>Birthday: {{ row.birthday|date }}</li>
                            <li>Gender: {{ row.gender|gender }}</li>
                            <li>Balance: {{ balance|get_balance(row.inst_id, row.stud_id) }}</li>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                {% endfor %} <!-- /END for loop -->
```

What am I missing here? I can run the function with no issue if I just run it from the file, but not when loading the template.

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out.. Filters in Jinja2 can only take one argument. I needed to use a context_processor that can take any amount of arguments

This was the code I used to fix it;

```
@app.context_processor
def utility_processor():
    def get_stud_balance(inst_id, stud_id):
        inst_id = int(inst_id)
        stud_id = int(stud_id)
        balance = 0
        stud_balance = Packages.query.filter(Packages.inst_id == inst_id, Packages.stud_id == stud_id).all()
        if stud_balance:
            for row in stud_balance:
                balance += row.balance
            return balance
        else:
            return None
    return dict(get_stud_balance=get_stud_balance)
```

Comment: This would have fixed it, `<li>Balance: {{ row.inst_id|get_balance(row.stud_id) }}</li>`